# Orbeon Forms: Displaying Version on Form

Tags: orbeon

This is my first post in this forum, so be gentle with me!!

My client wants to be able to view the form version on specific forms, and a suggestion was to use the following syntax in a control: fr:form-version()

However, this only displays the value "1" when the form is actually at version "4".

Any ideas?

PeteA

Used syntax in a control: fr:form-version()

Comment: Are you may be getting this when using Test from Form Builder? If so, what you're getting is the "version of Form Builder" (which isn't versioned, hence 1 being returned). However, you should not get this if you are opening the form's `/new` page. -Alex

Comment: It's my understanding that this is in the context of offline support. In that context, the embedding application passes, via API, the app name, form name, and form version. Then the `fr:form-version()` should return the version name passed through that API. It might be that the code that does the embedding, which is not written by Orbeon, fails to pass the correct form version. Can you check that on your end with the relevant programmers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `xxf:instance('fr-parameters-instance')/form-version`. It work only in runner, not while testing in builder.

Comment: @PeteAtkin If this answer is the solution to your question, please mark it as accept (check mark symbol).